# JQuery Toggle next class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, show-hide

I am making a blogging website and want to have headers or links show the post when clicked, I have it working so they all open when one is clicked but I just want it to be the one below the header

**JQuery  :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.slidingDiv').hide();
    $('.show_hide').show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
    });

});
```

**PHP :**

```
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{
    print "
      <a href='#' class='show_hide'>Article name</a>
      <div class='slidingDiv'>
          Fill this space with really interesting content. 
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
    ";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to select only the next `.slidingDiv`

```
$(this).next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
```

**Snippet**

```js
$('.slidingDiv').hide();
$('.show_hide').show();

$('.show_hide').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='show_hide'>Article name</a>
<div class='slidingDiv'>
  Fill this space with really interesting content.
</div>
<br>
<br>
<a href='#' class='show_hide'>Article name</a>
<div class='slidingDiv'>
  Fill this space with really interesting content.
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should find the next `.slidingDiv` element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.slidingDiv').hide();
    $('.show_hide').show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function() {
        // 'this' is now the clicked .show_hide element
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: This is wrong. The `.slidingDiv` is not a child of `.show_hide`